# Sorting a list in prolog based on 2 keys

Tags: sorting, prolog, key

let's suppose that I have this list.

```
A=[(a,1), (b,3), (d,2), (c,2)]
```

I wanna sort it based on 2 things, first I check the numbers, if they are the same I need to do it by the letter, for example this will be ordered as:

```
S=[(a,1), (c,2), (d,2), (b,3)]
```

If I use this

```
sort(2, @=<, A, S).
```

what I get is the list ordered but just based on the number, how can I add that plus control?

Comment: Do you have [predsort/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3)?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I don't think predsort/3 is correct. Can you give an example. Instead [order_by/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=order_by/2) is what I would use. [Order_by/2 examples](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/order-by-2-examples/2667)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I found your examples and while it will work, IMHO it is more work than necessary. The two different types, `letters` and `numbers` already have a means of sorting, so why not use that.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

```
sort1(L , S) :-
    predsort([R,(A,B),(C,D)]>>compare(R,(B,A),(D,C)), L, S).

sort2(L, S) :-
    findall((A,B), order_by([asc(B),asc(A)], member((A,B),L)), S).

sort3(L, S) :-
    maplist([(X,Y),(Y,X)]>>true, L, M),
    msort(M, M1),
    maplist([(X,Y),(Y,X)]>>true, M1, S).
```

Some examples:

```
?- A=[(a,1), (b,3), (d,2), (a,0), (c,2), (b,3)], time(sort1(A,S)).
% 53 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
A = [(a, 1),  (b, 3),  (d, 2),  (a, 0),  (c, 2),  (b, 3)],
S = [(a, 0),  (a, 1),  (c, 2),  (d, 2),  (b, 3)].

?- A=[(a,1), (b,3), (d,2), (a,0), (c,2), (b,3)], time(sort2(A,S)).
% 100 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.001 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
A = [(a, 1),  (b, 3),  (d, 2),  (a, 0),  (c, 2),  (b, 3)],
S = [(a, 0),  (a, 1),  (c, 2),  (d, 2),  (b, 3),  (b, 3)].

?- A=[(a,1), (b,3), (d,2), (a,0), (c,2), (b,3)], time(sort3(A,S)).
% 29 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
A = [(a, 1),  (b, 3),  (d, 2),  (a, 0),  (c, 2),  (b, 3)],
S = [(a, 0),  (a, 1),  (c, 2),  (d, 2),  (b, 3),  (b, 3)].
```

Execution time for a huge list:

```
?- N is 10**6, 
   length(L, N), 
   maplist([(X,Y)]>>(random(1,N,X), random(1,N,Y)), L), 
   time(sort1(L,A)), 
   time(sort2(L,B)), 
   time(sort3(L,C)), 
   fail.

% 76,846,271 inferences, 13.063 CPU in 13.171 seconds (99% CPU, 5882968 Lips)
% 4,000,076 inferences, 3.063 CPU in 3.140 seconds (98% CPU, 1306147 Lips)
% 4,000,005 inferences, 2.375 CPU in 2.375 seconds (100% CPU, 1684213 Lips)
false.
```

It seems that is best to use `maplist/3` combined with `msort/2`.

Comment: If you base that "best" judgement on the number of inferences, that's misleading. Sorting in SWI-Prolog is implemented in C, so no inferences are counted for it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about actually lambda-izing the predsort itself. Nice.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Now I don't have to write an answer.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: That's true, but the overall execution time remains better for the third alternative.

Comment: Interesting, on my machine with SWI 7.6.4 `sort2` takes 2 seconds, `sort3` takes 10 seconds. Looks like lambdas are slow on this version.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`sort/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4) '@=<' means "sort ascending, but do not eliminate duplicates".

If we accept duplicate elimination, we can adapt the metapredicate [`predsort/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3) to our needs.

```
predsort(+Pred, +List, -Sorted)
```

This is just another form of the "sorting methods" known from other programming languages. For example, in Java there is [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) which takes a `Comparator` interface. Here, `predsort/3` takes a predicate name `Pred` (or a partially filled-in predicate call) as callable procedure. Same thing.

The predicate [`compare/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3) is exactly what we need for element comparison as it compares whole terms using the [standard order of terms](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder):

```
?- compare(D,(a,1),(b,3)).
D =  (<).

?- compare(D,(a,1),(a,3)).
D =  (<).

?- compare(D,(a,3),(a,1)).
D =  (>).

?- compare(D,(b,3),(a,1)).
D =  (>).
```

However, it compares by first subelement first, second subelement second (or more correctly, by the order of arguments of the compound term with functor name `,`)

So we have to reverse these first. This is done with another metapredicate, [`maplist/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) where the "predicate that maps" elements of one list to elements of another will be "the predicate that reverses". As I am too lazy to add a separate predicate for that, I will write it "inline" using [`library(yall)`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall): `[(C,N),(N,C)]>>true` is equivalent to `reverse((C,N),(N,C))`.

And so:

```
my_sort(ListIn,ListOut) :-
   maplist([(C,N),(N,C)]>>true,ListIn,List2),
   predsort(compare,List2,List3),
   maplist([(C,N),(N,C)]>>true,ListOut,List3).
```

And so:

```
?- my_sort([(a,1), (b,3), (d,2), (c,2)], Out).
Out = [(a, 1),  (c, 2),  (d, 2),  (b, 3)].
```

Note that using `(A,B)` structures as pairs is less than perfect style - `,` is the conjunction. Use actual pairs instead: `A-B` (i.e. really `-(A,B)` structures).

Does it work for the empty list? Yes it does.

```
?- my_sort([],[]).
true.
```

More complete examples here:

- [Elements are commalists, as requested here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/prolog_exercises/hierarchical_sorting/hierarchical_sorting_with_commalists.pl)
- [Elements are pairs, which is more styleful](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/prolog_exercises/hierarchical_sorting/hierarchical_sorting_with_pairs.pl)